# Symfony2 swiftmailer functional test not working on Gitlab CI

Tags: symfony, phpunit, gitlab, swiftmailer, gitlab-ci

Im using Symfony2(.7) with swiftmailer to send out eamils. Made a function to send out emails to several users at once and a functional test for it as the symfony page suggested using profiler. The test is run by PHPUnit.

```
 $client->enableProfiler();
 $crawler = $client->request(...);

 if ($profile = $client->getProfile()) {
    $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());
}
```

The problem is that the test is ok on my locale pc(windows) but when runs on GitLab Community Edition 8.8.1's CI the test fails. The $mailCollector->getMessageCount() returns 0 and also $mailCollector->getMessages() an empty array.

CI config:

```
before_script:
  - composer config --global ..
  - composer self-update
  - composer install
  - cat app/config/parameters.yml
  - mysqlthings

stages:
  - test

test:
  script:
  - php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
  - php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
  - php app/console security:check
  - php app/console cache:clear --env=test
  - php -d zend_extension=xdebug.so phpunit.phar -c app/
```

dev cfg:

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

test cfg:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        enabled: true

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true

security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            http_basic: ~
```

Btw these files are the same on gitlab and my locale.
I also tried mailer with these:

```
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    mailer_port: 465
```

and with a real mailer server as my last hope..
Do i need some additional settings on CI or what can be the problem? 
Thx.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am also ran into this problem.

Comment: Sorry but i can't remember but don't think so

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gitlab ci too, and never had this problem - i also dont think its a problem with the CI-Runner.

are you sure you have this in the config_test.yml and using test env when you test local?:

```
framework:
   profiler:
       enabled: true
```

Comment: Its enabled of course :/ also the test enters the if branch and i got the mail collector too so these are working but messagecount is 0 on CI but thx for your reply

Comment: why is your db setup in the --env=dev (default)?

Comment: `parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: somename
    database_user: root
    database_password: null

cfg:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
       
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true`